# How to use IMPORTRANGE across discontinuous columns? (Or, how to omit columns?)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange

How are [discontinuous](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/69278638/google-sheets-query-how-to-exclude-certain-columns-from-query-results-display?hl=en) columns imported?  Here, the import is inclusive from `B3` to `D7` as:

[image: import]

Here, the formula is:

```
=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GvgMrjtfW2_TBO_stxYdIQMwTo8ODUJTdfUtMIYqqaM/edit#gid=0","data!B3:d7")
```

Where column `C` should be omitted.  The syntax to omit columns is unknown to me, but I tried:

```
=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GvgMrjtfW2_TBO_stxYdIQMwTo8ODUJTdfUtMIYqqaM/edit#gid=0","data!B3:B99,D3:D99")
```

Something along the lines of:

```
=QUERY(data!B1:Q,"SELECT B,D")
```

per the answer from Daniele would probably work, but cannot seem to incorporate that into the import.  That query, on its own, does select columns as expected.  However, it's seemingly not wired or connected to the worksheet and so isn't dynamic.  Query results are static, presumably.

data is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSlu3KLUXCu5zuOzgbvfUnljFrqgqpN0sOCOV0GFiRcpxGavXu-CbjTz2NbWt2NlzE9FqPatMRpDNRQ/pubhtml) and the import is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR4MLlR7J_RUm0K5ONmAA1HVlg_8D3XsGsqUYGBFrYqT4lxAf6GwsVsf26uLlK2oqg6ZCxGz_WLb2f0/pubhtml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Query()` like this:

```
=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GvgMrjtfW2_TBO_stxYdIQMwTo8ODUJTdfUtMIYqqaM/edit#gid=0","data!B3:d7"),"select Col1,Col3")
```

Comment: It doesn't see to let me enter all of that into the cell..?  Maybe there's a setting to enable long formula's.

Comment: just copy and paste :) you can also resize the formula bar by pulling it down